How to prevent a bash script from running repeatedly at the start of the terminal
I am physically connected to the machine an I use Arch linux. I use Arabic in the terminal and I use BiCon to add bidirectional support for the terminal (I am using st).
I want the program to start automatically when i open the terminal and clear the message that it outputs when it starts so I made a script:
$ cat biconscript
bicon 
clear

and I put it in .bashrc and here is the output the bicon line is run repeatedly.

What can I add to the bash script to stop after its executed once.
$ cat .bashrc

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

#alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ls='lsd'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias p='sudo pacman'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../../'
alias ....='cd ../../../'
alias ll='lsd -l -F'
alias la='lsd -aF '
alias sdn='sudo shutdown now'
alias q='exit'
alias update='p -Syu'
alias changeb='feh --bg-scale --randomize ~/Downloads/wall/'
export EDITOR=nvim #setting nvim as the default editor
export MANPAGER="nvim +Man!"
PS1='\[\e[38;5;232;107m\]>\[\e[48;5;252m\]>\[\e[48;5;251m\]>\[\e[0m\] \[\e[38;5;26;1m\]@\[\e[0m\] \[\e[1m\]\w\[\e[38;5;46m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
set -o vi       #set vim mode
shopt -s autocd #no need to type cd to change the directory
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
eval "$(zoxide init bash)" #adds the "z" command that is related to the zoxide app it works like the command "cd" but smarter
function yy() {            # allows yazi to exist with changing the current directory
  local tmp="$(mktemp -t "yazi-cwd.XXXXXX")"
  yazi "$@" --cwd-file="$tmp"
  if cwd="$(cat -- "$tmp")" && [ -n "$cwd" ] && [ "$cwd" != "$PWD" ]; then
    builtin cd -- "$cwd"
  fi
  rm -f -- "$tmp"
}
biconscript #script to add arabic


I think the script is run once, else you will see the effect of clear. To be sure, add an echo test

@GiacomoCatenazzi I tried adding an echo and the output is the same only the first line is repeating. Where do you think is the problem ?

Please [edit] your question and show us the full .bashrc. Also clarify how you are connecting to the machine. Are you there physically, or are you doing it over ssh or something else?

I am a beginner to linux and to writing questions thanks for your advice @terdon.

Thanks for the update! So, biconscript is the name of the script containing just bicon and clear? Or is there anything else? And where have you saved biconscript? Also, what happens if you add echo hello to your ~/.bashrc? Do you then see the echo command being run multiple times also?

Yes, biconscript is the name of the script containing bicon and clear and its in /usr/local/bin
and when i write echo hello to .bashrc it runs once

what happens if you remove clear from the script thus leaving just bicon in the script? since bicon modifies the behavior of the terminal I'm wondering if the clear is forcing some sort of reinitialization of the terminal (in this case sourcing .bashrc again); I'd also suggest opening an issue with the bicon developer(s)

@markp-fuso almost. It forks a new shell, so the bashrc is re-read and enters an infinite loop.

bicon has quite limited capabilities. It works decently as long as you view an app's output, or type text without typos. According to my experiences, as soon as you press Backspace once or twice while typing some input, its display falls apart. If you're often working with RTL text, may I recommend to instead switch to a terminal emulator that natively supports BiDi, such as VTE-based ones? You'll get a much better experience, and (in VTE) with escape sequences you can still control when to and when not to reorder the letters, should you need to switch back and forth.

Should it maybe be added to your .bash_profile instead of .bashrc so it's only executed once, at login? bicons man page says "If  the variable SHELL exists, the shell forked by bicon..." which is a big clue not to call it from your .bashrc as that'll be sourced by every shell that's spawned so you'll be calling bicon recursively.

It looks like bicon always starts a new shell session and so re-reads your ~/.bashrc which then calls bicon which then re-reads your ~/.bashrc, which then calls bicon on and on and on for ever. This is implied by the tool's man page which states:

SHELL  If  the  variable SHELL exists, the shell forked by bicon will be that shell. If SHELL is not set, the Bourne shell is assumed.  (Most shells set this variable automatically).

So bicon forks a new shell, which is why you see this happening. So you cannot add this tool to your ~/.bashrc that simply, I'm afraid. However, you can wrap it in a simple if that first checks if a bicon instance is running and only launches if there is none:
if ! pkill -0 bicon; then
  bicon
fi
clear

It's important to have the clear outside the if because we need that to be executed by the spawned shell, so only if bicon is running. Now, this works, but it means you only have bicon running in the first terminal you open and until you close that one. So if you open a new one while the old one is still running, you won't get bicon in the new one.
To get around this, if you are using bash, you can take advantage of the SHLVL variable. See man bash:

SHLVL  Incremented by one each time  an  instance  of  bash  is
started.

This variable counts the number of bash instances you have started in the current session. On graphical systems, this will likely be 2 when you open a terminal, presumably because your desktop environment is already running in one bash instance:

If you open a new shell as a different user though, it should be 1:
terdon@oregano ~ $ sudo -iu bib
[bib@oregano ~]$ echo $SHLVL 
1
[bib@oregano ~]$ 

So, assuming your system is like mine and you have 2 for new terminals, you can add this to your ~/.bashrc:
if [ $SHLVL -le 2 ]; then
     bicon
fi
clear

That will only launch bicon once per opened terminal.
Test on your system, check if in a new terminal your SHLVL is 1 or 2, and adapt accordingly (you might want to use -le 1 instead of -le 2 if your value is 1).

I have echo $SHLVL and it is 3.
I tried the answer you suggested and it seems that the if condition is not evaluating as true, I tried with echo and there was no result. Then I tried with [ $SHLVL -ge 3 ] and it went back to the problem of repeating.

@N0tus3r if you mean that is what you see without the bicon, then you should use if [ $SHLVL -le 3 ]; then ... in your ~/.bashrc.

Putting if [ $SHLVL -le 3 ]; then ... in a script and then putting the script in .bashrc does not work however putting the contents directly in .bashrc works. Thank you for your time and effort.

@N0tus3r well yes, it won't work in a script since that is more shell levels down. That's why I suggested putting it directly in your bashrc file.

The problem is the recursive starting of new shells.
Firstly, check the documentation for bicon to see if it has a mode or option that does not start a new shell.
If that doesn't work, read on...
Doing things that are inherently recursive, and then inserting extra code to prevent the recursion, makes for a brittle design. You could wind up locking yourself out by making a minor change to your .bash_profile.
Consider changing your login shell from bash to something that sets SHELL=/bin/bash and then launches bicon; this becomes the program that's launched in each new terminal.
Likely this would need to be a script in your ~/.local/bin or ~/bin directory, and you'd need to specify its full path:
b=$( command -v bicon )
s=$HOME/.bin/bicon-login
mkdir -p "${s%/*}"
printf > "$s" '%s\n' \
  '#!/bin/bash' \
  "SHELL=/bin/bash exec -l $b"
chmod a=rx "$s"
sudo usermod -s "$s" "$USER"

Note that the #!/bin/bash line is independent of your login shell; I've selected bash because it supports exec -l, which tells bicon that it's actually your login shell.
Lastly, your terminal program might have been configured to use bash explicitly. This should be disabled, so that it uses your login shell.
